# oldValue for dates in Google Apps Script

Tags: javascript, events, google-apps-script, calendar

I am using an onEdit trigger to trigger a Google Apps Script. Essentially, I am using the results of a Form to populate a calendar event. Once I've created the calendar event, I want to be able to keep it in sync with the form entry. So if someone edits the form data, I want to edit the calendar event. Unfortunately, since there is no getEventById storing the eventId is not enough.

I was thinking I might be able to use the event['oldValue'] which stores the event time to figure out when the event used to be (in case it changes) to get a list of events at that time which will allow me to iterate through a small number of events to find the calendar event.

Unfortunately, the date object comes out as a weird floating point number that I can't parse. e.g: 1/19/2016 20:00:00 comes out as 42388.791666666664 which I really don't understand.

I did have another thought, should I just use a regular HTTP get call to get the event I want? I'm not exactly sure how to do that from within a Google Apps Script

Comment: What is the value of the date in the spreadsheet?  What is the format of the column?  What is the line of code that gets the value?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe late, but you can see the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38815858/google-apps-script-convert-float-to-date)

```js
var x = 42521.015713761575;

// seconds in day = 24 * 60 * 60 = 86400
var date = new Date(1899, 11, 30, 0, 0, x * 86400);
```