# Google Apps Script _ Convert float to date

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a cell in my google spreadsheet with the value of 5/31/2016 0:22:38, but when I wrote a script to fetch the data it returns 42521.015713761575. I've tried some codes from [jquery convert number to date?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5722919/jquery-convert-number-to-date) but most returns dates back to 1970. How would I be able to format the said float into the date specified above? thanks... :)

Comment: Can you please update your question with your script?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to read the correct time values from Google Spreadsheet](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17715841/how-to-read-the-correct-time-values-from-google-spreadsheet)

Answer (score 5):

This is apparently a number of days elapsed since December 30, 1899, 00:00:00.

You can convert it back to a UTC date with the following code (note that months are zero-based, so December = 11):

```js
var x = 42521.015713761575;

// seconds in day = 24 * 60 * 60 = 86400
var date = new Date(Date.UTC(1899, 11, 30, 0, 0, x * 86400));

console.log(date.toUTCString());
```

Comment: Wed, 01 Jun 2016 16:22:37 GMT is the result on JSFiddle... getting closer? maybe a timezone problem? :)

Comment: @MansonMamaril I've updated my code to create a UTC date, so that at least everyone is seeing the same thing. :-) I've also updated the reference day (2 days before Jan 1st, 1900) so that it matches the expected result. But this still looks very hackish and unreliable. I would recommend to look for a dedicated method. (Are you sure Google is not providing one?)

Comment: I've tried a utilities.formatdate with tutorials from different stackoverflow but they're also providing dates from 1970...

Comment: I don't know if there's an actual function to return what is written... I use this function `sheet.getRange(startingrow, startingcol, lastrow, lastcol).getValues();` to get data in batch but only float is returned when the fetching lands on the date value...

Comment: [This post](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/87186/why-does-google-spreadsheet-use-days-as-unit-of-time-when-entering-a-number) suggests that the reference time in Google spreadsheets is indeed December 30, 1899 00:00:00. So it seems like my hackish answer may actually be correct.